# If the invoice was created offline, try creating an offline credit memo. Magento2.3.4

Tags: error, payment, magento2.3.4, refund

> Getting **error** when try to create online refund.

```
If the invoice was created offline, try creating an offline credit memo.
```

[image]

Comment: I got the same issue. Did you succeed to understand and fix your problem?

Comment: i have issue of custom payment methods

Comment: Is this issue solved ?

Comment: You don't have a payment transaction inserted in the database with txn_id that corresponds to the transaction_id set on the invoice.